# Adding Custom Fields for Img in Posts

Tags: plugins, php, custom-field, shortcode

I'm wondering how I'd be able to set a custom field within my Wordpress posts. I want to have a field available to add an image via the Post dashboard - that has a max width & max height set, I want the image to always float to the left within the posts (Text wrapping around via the right).

Can anyone recommend a plugin for this, or the PHP snippet that I could include to do so (I could add to single.php or functions.php, right?)

Thanks as always!

Comment: Do you mean [post thumbnails](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails)? Or are you looking for something different?

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem? :)

Comment: Any follow-up on this question, from the OP? **WPSE is a *Question and Answer* site, not a *drive-by support forum***. If the answer below solved your problem, you should indicate that, by *clicking the check mark* next to the answer. If it *didn't* solve your problem, you should add comments indicating why not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use  the post thumbnail feature. Add support for this feature with this line in your functions.php file:

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
```

You can also set a new thumbnail size that will be cropped on new added photos to use this in your theme. Add this code to set a new thumbnail size (also in the functions.php file):

```
add_image_size( 'large-feature', 500, 300, true );
```

The code above crops the picture to fit exact into 500x300 pixel. to let the width and heigh to be fluid (with a max width of 500 and a max height of 300) set the true property to `false`.

Finally add the thumbnail to the theme at the location you want. With this code:

```
echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'large-feature' );
```

That's it :) you enabled and customized a post thumbnail pictured! Hope this works for you :)

#### Edit

Adding a couple suggestions/best practices:

First, be sure to put the `functions.php` code inside a *callback*, hooked in appropriately; e.g.:

```
function theme_slug_setup_thumbnails() {
    // Enable featured image feature
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
    // Add custom image size for displaying
    // featured image within the post
    add_image_size( 'large-feature', 500, 300, true );

}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'theme_slug_setup_thumbnails' );
```

Second, wrap the template call in a conditional, and output the fully-formed HTML for the image:

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    the_post_thumbnail( 'large-feature' );
}
```

(I would also recommend using a unique slug for the custom image size, such as `theme-slug-large-feature', where`theme-slug`is the *slug* of your Theme name. Note that I also used`theme_slug`as a unique prefix for the`functions.php` callback function.)

Comment: Hope you don't mind the edits. Upvoted your asnswer. :)

Comment: Nice edit, now i learned something too ;) thank you!